# FlipView To Flip Eternaly

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-8

Is it possible to make a `FlipView` continue to "flip" at the end of the DataSource Items and start over at Index 0? Also same going the other way from -1 to Items.Count?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might not be supported built-in - there is a [`CarouselPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.carouselpanel.aspx) that sounds like it might do the trick if not for the fact that the documentation states it's only supported by `ComboBox`.